# Jazzy is not working as expected for generating swift documentation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, documentation, jazzy

After doing some research on the best way to document swift code. I came across Jazzy and how simple it was to implement. So I follow the installation section of the [Jazzy Documentation](https://github.com/Realm/jazzy). I run

```
sudo gem install jazzy
```

Then I navigate to the root of my project, in the terminal, and run `jazzy` which creates a folder called "docs" with a website that displays documentation for 1 class. I have 87 classes which I can visibly see jazzy looping through in the terminal output.

I've read the [NSHipster Tutorial](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) about documenting code which also links you to the [Jazzy Documentation](https://github.com/Realm/jazzy) as well as the [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH2-SW1). I've documented some code, which Xcode displays correctly in the side pane or right clicking the function or class. So i'm fairly certain that my syntax is correct.

I took some time to compare that 1 file to the another file that isn't being displayed and I don't see anything out of the ordinary with regards to format.

I'm running:

- jazzy version: 0.3.2
- Xcode version: 7.1
- Swift version: 2.1
- OS X El Capitan Version: 10.11

My overall question is; Why isn't jazzy producing documentation for all classes and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After reading more about jazzy more in depth I found this important piece of information.

> By default, jazzy only documents public declarations. To generate
>   documentation for declarations with a lower accessibility level
>   (internal or private), please set the --min-acl flag to internal or
>   private.

Which is in the trouble shooting portion of the [jazzy git hub page](https://github.com/realm/jazzy)

I ran jazzy with the following line to produce the documentation i expected:

```
jazzy --min-acl private
```

**Note** I should read everything before I decided something isn't working right.

Answer (score 11):

To make it even better. Use 
`jazzy --min-acl internal --skip-undocumented`
Explanation :
`--min-acl internal` this will include all functions, classes, structs in your documentary 
`--skip-undocumented` this will ignore all undocumented classes...

Comment: oo thanks, i was annoyed how it said like 68% documented

Comment: And is there a way to document all ACL (public, private, internal?)

If I use `--min-acl internal` I dont see the public methods being documented.

Comment: Add a documentation to the top of the class & it will work

Comment: Dude! You're awesome, I was literally looking for a flag like this. Thanks