# How to use jazzy to document my swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, document, jazzy

I want to document my swift project, and I find jazzy on the github.
after a look at the guide, I create a new simple project and want to have a try, here is my `ViewController` with some document info:

```
import UIKit
/**
a view controller
*/
class ViewController: UIViewController {
// MARK: property
/// a simple var
var hello = 200

// MARK: Func
/// view did load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print(add(2, b: 2))
}
/// did receiveMemoryWarning
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/// a document test func
func add(a:Int, b:Int)->Int{
    return a + b
    }
}
```

here is my command:

```
    ➜  DocumentDemo git:(master) ✗ jazzy --swift-version 2.1.1 \
--clean \
--author helloworld \
-x -scheme,DocumentDemo
Running xcodebuild
Parsing ViewController.swift (1/3)
Parsing AppDelegate.swift (2/3)
Parsing My.swift (3/3)
building site
jam out ♪♫ to your fresh new docs in `docs`
➜  DocumentDemo git:(master) ✗
```

and I expect the html to have some info about my view controller,but the result is nothing there:

[image]

I want to know how to use jazzy, hope some advices.

Comment: Search the wikis and issues of Jazzy on GitHub; there are several pitfalls. Also, there is a "default access-control-level" of visibility for Jazzy, and if I remember correctly it is `public` (not the default `protected`); that's why your docs end up empty I think.

Comment: @NicolasMiari  i tried public, this the issue, thanks a lot

Comment: Mmh... Did you try using a configuration file (.jazzy.yaml)? Mine starts with `clean: true \n min_acl: private`. This means anything above-and-including private is documented.

Comment: Save the file in the same directory where your `.xcodeproj` resides, and run jazzy from there, without arguments (it will read them from the file instead).

Comment: aha, it's perfect , now everything works fine .thanks again

Comment: You can specify the same options from the command line, but it's a pain to have to remember and type them every time.

Comment: i have changed acl to private but still everything is undocumented. any clue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jazzy is not working as expected for generating swift documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533188/jazzy-is-not-working-as-expected-for-generating-swift-documentation)

Answer (score 5):

By default, Jazzy only documents `public` classes, functions, properties, etc. So you can do one of two things:

1. Add the `public` keyword to classes, methods and properties you want
   document.
2. [Change the privacy level](https://github.com/realm/jazzy#troubleshooting) that Jazzy will document. You can change
   this with the `--min-acl` flag:

   ```
   jazzy --swift-version 2.1.1 --min-acl=internal
   ```

Answer (score 3):

On swift 3 just

```
jazzy --min-acl=internal
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just run `jazzy`, jazzy just assume you want default access control level is `public`.

So unless we annotate things with `public`, the final document won't show theses. Default level is `internal`.

---

**Tip**

You can create a `.jazzy.yaml`, and put configuration in there. So after this, can just run.

`$ jazzy`

Jazzy will parse our configured yaml file.

Reference: [Siesta's jazzy](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/.jazzy.yaml)